# Header search paths with gcc using C_INCLUDE_PATH

Tags: c, gcc, header, include-path, user-profile

i'm confused about the following include files(with GCC)

i've A.c and B.c in folder AAA

and B.h in folder BBB

in A.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "B.h"

main()
{
    errPrint();
}
```

in B.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "B.h"
void errPrint(void)   
{
    printf("err info\n");
}
```

in B.h:

```
#ifndef _B_H
#define _B_H
void errPrint(void);
#endif
```

now i run the command:

`#gcc -I /BBB A.c B.c -o exeobj`

it's OK.
but it seems a little boring that i have to use "-I" to specify header when in 
other folder.
so i edit my "/etc/profile" file and added

```
C_INCLUDE_PATH=/BBB  
export C_INCLUDE_PATH
```

to specify the header folder, then

```
echo $C_INCLUDE_PATH
```

it shows the right route.
but when i compile:

```
#gcc -c A.c B.c
```

error shows:

```
error: B.h: No such file or directory
```

i don't know where went wrong, anybody have clues about it, any suggestions are weclome.

note: i'm a newbie and can't use Makefile yet...

Comment: I set up the structure you describe above and tried it with gcc 4.7.2, and it worked as expected.  So I don't think there's anything fundamentally wrong with what you're trying to do, but I'm not sure why it's not working for you.

Comment: This works just fine for me as well. Have you tried defining the environmental variable at the command line? I can't think of a reason for a shell to not execute /etc/profile, but how about trying  `export PATH=\BBB; gcc -c A.c B.c`

Comment: er, i mistake ur meaning, u mean 'export CPATH=\BBB', not 'export PATH=\BBB' right?

Comment: What do you get if you run `export | grep C_INCLUDE`?

Comment: it shows the right place i included, 'declare -x C_INCLUDE_PATH="/home/workspace/routine/include'.

Comment: And B.h is definitely in that directory?

Comment: yeah, as i said, '#gcc -I /BBB A.c B.c -o exeobj' worked...

Answer (score 0):

in A.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <B.h>

main()
{
    errPrint();
}
```

in B.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <B.h>
void errPrint(void)   
{
    printf("err info\n");
}
```

If want to use `#include "file.h"` you gotta specified path example: `"/BBB/B.h"`

For more info you can read  [In the C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) section 6.10.2, paragraphs 2 to 4.

**EDIT**: After test. try it please.

```
echo -e "C_INCLUDE_PATH=/BBB\nexport C_INCLUDE_PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile

source ~/.bash_profile
```

and now

```
gcc A.c B.c
```

Good Lucks :)

Comment: That actually shouldn't make a difference, I think.  The difference between "" and <> is that "" also searches the current directory first, but then they both fall back to the same search algorithm after that.  I've never tried to use C_INCLUDE_DIR before, though....

Comment: The GCC manual [backs up](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html#Search-Path) rra's claim.

Comment: @Quentin Perez: The section 6.10.2 you cite explicitly says that in the case `#include "foo.h"` the file is "searched for in an implementation-defined manner".

Comment: After test with the variable C_INCLUDE_PATH my file.h is not found too.

Comment: The implementation-defined manner in which gcc handles "" in #include is to search the same directory as the C source file first, and then fall back on the normal <> path.

Comment: @QuentinPerez Yeah, it works for me too, but so does the situation in the original question, so I'm not sure what's going wrong for Takechiyocn.

Comment: well,  the directory specified by environment variable "C_INCLUDE_PATH"  is searched after current directory , and last is normal<> path, why it is OK on rra but NG on Quentin Perez, factors on system environment are possible?